# indexation and Canonical URL Issue with Personal GitHub-hosted Site on Google Search

Tags: canonical-url, 404, google-selected-canonical

I encountered an issue with my personal site hosted on GitHub, as it does not appear in Google search results. Upon investigating Google Search Console, I received the message: "The page is not indexed: Duplicate page: Google has not chosen the same canonical URL as the user."

Upon further inspection, I discovered that Google has selected a different canonical URL associated with a site that I deleted (HTTP 404) approximately three months ago. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to that deleted site. Despite attempting to remove it using Google Search Console, Google still recognizes it as the canonical site.

And the deleted link continues to be indexed by Google.

I no longer have access to modify the deleted site or implement a redirect. how can i resolve this issue?

Thank you,

I attempted to resolve the issue by adding a canonical URL directly to the site, hoping it would force Google not to select another URL as canonical but it didn't work. Additionally, i attempted to delete the old site through Google Search Console but the site continues to be indexed.

Comment: I can't do a 301 redirect as i no longer have access to the older site.

Comment: Is the older site a domain like .com, .net, etla with a registered name and DNS record that you can access, or is a subdomain, (name.wordpress.com) or a page that exists on a site (sites.google.com/home/page/) where you don't have access to the DNS settings? ... if it has a DNS record another host (even free) can be used to do the 301 redirect. If it is a page on another site, can you recreate a page - a new one which you can place a meta tag on?

Comment: Have you considered making changes to the page so it is no longer a duplicate of the old page? More entity SEO would change the page and give it a gain of knowledge which google rewards.

Comment: Last Q does the old site have links pointing towards it? From social media / profile accounts which you can update?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'll make some changes to modify the page to avoid duplication and i'll post back if it doesn't work. Additionally, I've already updated all social media links directing to the site.

Answer (score 2):

"Solved". I sent a message on Google Search Console letting them know the situation and the fixed it, they removed the old site cache.

But out of curiosity I duplicated the site again to see if doing some minor changes help. It only works if you change the overall format of the site or the texts/links in it, changing the background or some colors will not work.

Thank you everyone for the advice.